# How to implement RVIZ render panel into a GUI created with qtcreator

Tags: gazebo, rviz, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a GUI with qtcreator for making more usable an existing ROS script that utilize RVIZ.

Is it possible to implement inside a qt window an RVIZ render panel?
Is it also possible to implement in the same GUI some buttons for using some functionalities provided by RVIZ, like the 2DSET.

I'm using ROS indigo, ubuntu 14.04 and qt 5.

This is an example of the GUI:
http://projects.ira.disco.unimib.it/public/tmp/qt-rviz.png

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240808/how-to-implement-rviz-render-panel-into-a-gui-created-with-qtcreator/) by [Teo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27648/teo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're going to want to look at [librviz](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Teo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27648/teo/) on 2016-08-01**:
I saw that tutorial before, but my problem is that I've already created a GUI with qtcreator and i can modify it only with the design editor.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-08-01**:
Almost all the RViz components are QWidgets, which can be embedded like any other. And qtcreator's .ui files are just XML, so you can always edit them directly if it comes to that...